# HTML force new page + absolute position

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a program that creates a report in HTML. That HTML file is displayed in a TWebBrowser component (Delphi) and basically prints the page using this code:

```
WebBrowserComponent.ControlInterface.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, vIn, vOut) ;
```

The report needs to match a pre-printed form. In order to place values exactly at the right place, I use CSS code like this:

```
#date_of_invoice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3mm;
    top: 90mm;
    width: 29mm;
    height: 5mm;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This was a working solution. Any new client that wished to use this program could hire a web designer and customize the HTML template for their needs. Today I got a new request, saying that there should be more than one pages printed at once. I can force new pages by adding:

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;">
    content on page...
</div>
```

However, when absolute positions are used then page-break-after has no effect on the absolutely positioned elements. So here is the question: is it possible somehow to position elements relative to the top left corner of the current page? I know that HTML does not have a "current page" concept. But since we have "page-break-after" CSS property, I was hoping there might be something similar for positioning elements relative to the current page. Maybe there is a trick to place a small invisible element in the top left corner and position other elements relative to that invisible point of reference?

The other option would be to reimplement all reports from scratch and use PDF instead of HTML. Which would be a very bad idea because there are already several reports made with HTML, and I don't want to redesign them by hand, and then I don't want to tell my customers that they won't be able to customize the reports in the future.